# I can‘t close the Form when I try to add code to manipulate the DataGridView in a WinForms application，and there are no compiler error messages

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to develop a WinForms application using C#. I'm using the DataGridView component and I want to add a column when a button is pressed. Additionally, when the mouse focus leaves the current area, I want to check if there are any empty cells in the DataGridView. If there are, I want to automatically delete the column containing that cell and sort the DataGridView.
Here is my Code:

```
private void dataGridView4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a list to store columns to be removed
    List<DataGridViewColumn> columnsToRemove = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();

    // Iterate through each column in the DataGridView (starting from index 1, skipping the first column)
    for (int i = dataGridView4.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView4.Columns[i];
        bool isEmpty = true;

        // Iterate through all cells in the current column
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
        {
            // Check if the cell is empty
            if (row.Cells[column.Index].Value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[column.Index].Value.ToString()))
            {
                // If at least one cell is not empty, set isEmpty to false and break out of the inner loop
                isEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If all cells in the current column are empty, add the column to the list of columns to be removed
        if (isEmpty)
        {
            columnsToRemove.Add(column);
        }
    }

        // Remove the columns
        foreach (var columnToRemove in columnsToRemove)
        {
            dataGridView4.Columns.Remove(columnToRemove);
        }

    // Refresh the dataGridView and rename/reorder the columns
    RefreshDataGridViewIndex();
}
```

[image]

When I leave the area, there is no more blank columns, **but I can't Close this Form**.
[image]

The compiler doesn't provide any relevant error messages, but I can't close the Form. I don't know why this is happening. Can someone help me?

What's more, the following situation can also prevent me from closing the current Form.[image]

After **Trigger this code**:
[image]

In fact, this is exactly the effect I want this piece of code to achieve, that is, to delete the column to which the empty cell belongs when it exists. I hope this situation can provide more clues to help you locate the problem.

I tried to debug by reverse outputting or adding **MessageBox.Show** to locate where is the bug, but since the compiler didn't give me any clear error messages, I find it difficult to proceed.
I can use other way or just give up my idea, but I just want to know why this happened.

---------------------------new clue------------------------
I just discovered a new clue, but I don't understand the mechanism behind the issue. The layout of my controls is as shown in the figure below.
[image]
Previously, I bound private void dataGridView4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) to the GroupBox instead of the DataGridView because I didn't want the behavior of clearing empty columns to trigger when I clicked on the GroupBox. I bound the event to the GroupBox's **Leave** event.
[image]
However, now that I've unbound the **Leave** event from the GroupBox and instead bound private void dataGridView4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) to the **Mouse_Leave** event of my DataGridView, it miraculously works correctly.
[image]
I'm wondering why this is the case. Are there any differences in the processing logic between the **Leave** event and **Mouse_Leave** event that would prevent me from closing my Form? I hope someone can help clarify my confusion. Thank you!

Comment: *"I tried to debug by reverse outputting or adding MessageBox.Show"*. That's not debugging. Use the actual debugger. Set breakpoints and step through the code line by line where appropriate, examining the state at each step. You need to explain how EXACTLY you're trying to close the form too, as there are multiple ways. If the form won't close then some of your code must be preventing it doing so, so that's the first thing you should use breakpoints for. Place them on all relevant methods. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Jmcilhinney Thank you for your advice, I'm trying to close my Form by directly clicking the close button at the top right corner of the Form. I will attempt to debug using breakpoints to see what's happening.

Comment: Does the grid have focus when you're trying to close the form? Do you see the same behaviour if you shift focus to another control first?

Comment: What kinda catches me of guard is `int columnIndex = columnsToRemove[i];`. Is this just a mistake that came when you copied your code into stackoverflow, or whats going on here?

Comment: @SMSTJ Yes, Thank you! I made a mistake when I try to copy code, I correct it to the original version. Using index was one of my attempts.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Of course, I definitely tried to close the window after moving the focus away from the DataGridView. I did this by clicking on any other Control to move the focus.

Comment: Is this From the only part/window of the Application?

Comment: I think we might need a bit more code. At this moment it seems to me that your removal code is fine but the issue might be with something outside of that. Like are there any references to coloumns/items we should know. And what does your add coloumn method look like?

Comment: Ok this wont fix the issue but it might give us an Idea how far you get. Override the closing event Method 
`protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)`
then in that method do a if(e.Cancel) and then pop up a messgae Box telling you that the close has been canceled. What this does is to let is check IF the Form even tries to close and if it has an issue leading it to have a ture Cancel value

Comment: @SMSTJ I updated some clue and detail for this problem, If you need Add Column buttom code, here it is. `private void AddColumnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 20 columns at most
    if (dataGridView4.ColumnCount < 20)
    {
        //New Coloum Index for ColumnTitle to Show, should be plus 1
        string ColumnNum = (dataGridView4.ColumnCount + 1).ToString();
        dataGridView4.Columns.Add("Section" + ColumnNum, "段" + ColumnNum);
        dataGridView4.Columns[dataGridView4.ColumnCount-1].Width =100 ;
    }
}`

Comment: Ah ok just for the future, name the events after the things they are actually attached to. Makes things a lot easier for questions like theese.

Comment: @SMSTJ 
I tried your suggestion of overriding the OnFormClosing method of the form. Now even after binding private void dataGridView4_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) to the **Leave** event of a GroupBox, the Form will still closes Normally. You can provide your answer, I will select it as useful response. Thank you for your patient guidance! By the way, Here is my Code: ` protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnFormClosing(e);

     //MessageBox.Show("Close");
     e.Cancel = false;
 }`

Comment: Handling the `MouseLeve` event rather than the `Leave` event is wrong because they are two very different things. `Leave` is raised when the control loses focus, while `MouseLeave` is raised when the mouse pointer moves outside the bounds of the control. `MouseLeave` can be raised whether or not the control has focus. `MouseLeave` should generally be used when you want the appearance to be different when the mouse if over the control and when not. You should not be doing things like removing columns on that event. That's a hack that works by accident, not a solution.

Comment: @jmcilhinney agreed. It should be done when `clicking` outside the Grid not just when the mouse is moved away

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for your guidance. I think you're right. Currently, I'm not using the 'Mouse_Leave' event. Instead, I followed SMSTJ 's suggestion to override the OnFormClosing event and still bind it to the Groupbox's 'Leave' event, and it works. If you have a better approach or understand the underlying logic behind this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @AkioZhao I think the Grids Leave event would be a bettwer Idea. I assume that some of the other buttons Save your changes and since thoose buttons are in your group box the epty cols could be saved which I assume you dont want.

Comment: If setting `e.Cancel` to `false` makes a difference then it must be getting set to `true` somewhere otherwise, so you should use the debugger to find that and determine why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do SOMETHING but it feel very dirty

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
    e.Cancel = false;
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```